# How to capture the image/screenshot during live stream in react js using external camera (with rtsp url)?

Tags: reactjs, node.js

I'm new to react js and trying to capture the image/screenshot during live stream in react js. With below code, canvas is capturing black

```
    import React, { useRef } from 'react';
    import axios from "axios";
    import Jsmpeg from './JsmpegPlayer';
    import './Help.css'; 

    const MyComponent = () => {

      let jsmpegPlayer = null;

      const captureScreenshot = () => {
        console.log('Capturing screenshot...');
        html2canvas(document.body).then(canvas => {
          console.log('Canvas:', canvas); // Log the canvas element
          const screenshot = canvas.toDataURL(true); // Convert canvas to base64 image data
          console.log('Screenshot:', screenshot); // Log the screenshot data URL
          const link = document.createElement('a');
          link.href = screenshot;
          link.download = 'screenshot.png';
          document.body.appendChild(link);
          link.click();
          document.body.removeChild(link);
          })
      };  

      return (
          <div>
          <Jsmpeg
              wrapperClassName="video-wrapper"
              videoUrl="ws://localhost:9999"
              
              onRef={ref => jsmpegPlayer = ref}
            />
            <div className="buttons-wrapper">
              <button onClick={() => jsmpegPlayer.play()}>Play</button>
              <button onClick={() => jsmpegPlayer.pause()}>Pause</button>
              <button onClick={() => jsmpegPlayer.stop()}>Stop</button>
              <button onClick={() => {captureScreenshot();
              }}>Capture Screenshot</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      };

    export default MyComponent;
```

I have researched and found that in jsmpeg git https://github.com/phoboslab/jsmpeg#usage that preserveDrawingBuffer option is false by default and blocking the content. Tried to change it to true but found that html2canvas internally handles the rendering of the DOM elements to a canvas, and it does not expose an option to set preserveDrawingBuffer to true directly.

How can I resolve this to capture the screen shot with content in the canvas??